# Degree sum formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose the G = (V,E) is a connected graph with n vertices and n-1 edges. Use the degree-sum formula for vertices to prove that G has a vertex of degree 1.

I can't seem to find where to start in this.

Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: Surely you can *start* this.  Have you written down what the degree-sum formula says in this case?  Is it possible that every vertex is of degree $\ge 2?$  BTW, note that the statement is false when $n=1.$

Comment: i know that degree sum formula is sum of degrees = 2 times number of edges.How do i proceed further

Comment: So in this case, $2(n-1)=\sum{\deg(v)},$  and there are $n$ terms in the sum.  What can you conclude?

Comment: yeah , i get it .If i assume each vertex has degree 2 i will get sum as 2n but in lhs i have 2(n-1) hence there should be one vertex with degree 1.But how do i write /show it mathematically

Comment: You haven't completed the argument.  You have to note that in a connected graph with more that $1$ vertex, there are no vertices of degree $0$.  Otherwise, all you know is that some vertex has degree $<2$. I'll write out an argument.  Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: yeah that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that the statement is false for a graph with one vertex and no edges,so we shall prove the statement for $n>1.$  By the degree-sum formula, $$\sum_{v\in V}{\deg(v)}=2(n-1).$$  Since the sum has $n$ term, there must be a $v_0\in V$ such that $\deg(v_0) < 2$ as otherwise, we would have $\sum{\deg(v)\ge 2n > 2(n-1).}$ We cannot have $\deg(v_0)=0,$ since $G$ is a connected graph with more than one vertex, so $\deg(v_0)=1.$

Note that under the hypotheses, $G$ actually has at least **two** vertices of degree $1.$  Can you continue the proof to show that?